# PCF Autoscaler - Configure as Part of Deployment

Tags: autoscaling, cloud-foundry

I can bind an application to PCF Autoscaler on deployment by using the manifest.yml.  The application shows up in the Autoscaler UI, but now has to be manually enabled and configured.

How can we set up our deployment so that the application is automatically enabled and configured in PCF Autoscaler?  Can we set some values in the manifest.yml to control this?  Or is there a way to configure this through the PCF command line?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [autoscaling-cli-plugin](https://github.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/autoscaling-cli-plugin) on your build machine.

And you can then use a scripting thru your pipeline to apply settings, post deploy of the app.

Note: Just checked the plugin page. The prebuilt release only supports autoscaling by cpu. It needs to be updated to allow autoscaling by http requests etc.

Comment: When I try to install that plugin, I get an error:

Download attempt failed: Error downloading file from https://github.com/pivotal-cf-experimental/autoscaling-cli-plugin

Unable to install, plugin is not available from the given url.

Comment: git clone the repo. The plugin executable come in it. 
Depending on your platform, you may I have to build it by hand.